# Scrapy1.1/Python3 Removing string from string

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get data from an old html page.

Python3 
Debian
Scrapy 1.1

I have see a couple of example of what i'm trying to do here but for a reason that I don't understand I'm not able to reproduce with my results:

The info I want to get is the Contact Name here (John Doe)

```
<p><strong>Contact: <a href="http://www.example.com/t/search-title-Proprietor.html" style="color:#259cd5">Proprietor</a> John Doe</strong></p>
```

I'm able to return with Scrapy :

```
Contact: [u'Contact: ', u' John Doe']
```

The only problem is that the **"Contact:"** part is written in my CSV file...

```
Contact: , John Doe
```

I tried a bunch of regex and playing with the variable but I always get to another problem.

This is what i'm using to get the data :

```
item['Contact'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="main-contain"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/p[10]/strong/text()').extract()
```

I also tried with .replace() but I end up with

```
[u'', u' John Doe']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simple finally,

My variable contain a list. I need to .replace() on something in my list.

contact[1].replace("Contact: ", "")

fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options depending on the pattern used by the website to represent the contact:

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text='<p><strong>Contact: <a href="http://www.example.com/t/search-title-Proprietor.html" style="color:#259cd5">Proprietor</a> John Doe</strong></p>')
   ...:
```

In your example, the `strong` element has 3 children: 1 text node, a link and another text node:

```
In [3]: selector.xpath('.//p/strong/node()').extract()
Out[3]: 
['Contact: ',
 '<a href="http://www.example.com/t/search-title-Proprietor.html" style="color:#259cd5">Proprietor</a>',
 ' John Doe']
```

The XPath you use filters on immediate children that are text nodes:

```
In [4]: selector.xpath('.//p/strong/text()').extract()
Out[4]: ['Contact: ', ' John Doe']
```

You can select the last one using a `[last()]` predicate:

```
In [5]: selector.xpath('.//p/strong/text()[last()]').extract()
Out[5]: [' John Doe']
```

Scrapy selectors have an `.extract_first()` method to get a single value (or None) instead of the default list that you get with `.extract()`:

```
In [6]: selector.xpath('.//p/strong/text()[last()]').extract_first()
Out[6]: ' John Doe'
```

Further, you can get rid of the leading whitespace with XPath's `normalize-space()`:

```
In [7]: selector.xpath('normalize-space(.//p/strong/text()[last()])').extract_first()
Out[7]: 'John Doe'
```